Do GUT's really explain parity violation?
Every book on the Standard Model introduces early on the concept of left and right-handed quantum fields, defined as
\begin{align}
(\psi_L)_{\alpha} = \left(\frac{1-\gamma_5}{2}\right)_{\alpha \beta}\psi_{\beta} \\
(\psi_R)_{\alpha} = \left(\frac{1+\gamma_5}{2}\right)_{\alpha \beta}\psi_{\beta}
\end{align}
From here left $SU(2)$ doublets such as
\begin{pmatrix}
\nu_L \\
e_L
\end{pmatrix}
are defined, with $\psi$ changed by the corresponding particle type letter. Right-handed fields are singlets under $SU(2)_L$, so no doublets there.
From this point onward, all GUTs (like Pati-Salam, SU(5) or SO(10)) are said to contain $SU(2)_L$ and to explain it by embedding it in some larger group and getting it back through symmetry breaking.
My question is: what does it mean that, for example, the Pati-Salam model explains $SU(2)_L$? To me, the only thing it predicts is that some fields transform as singlets and some others as doublets under $SU(2)$. The fact that the doublets contain only left-handed fields is kept entirely unexplained.
It somehow appears as if "transforming as a doublet" is taken to be the equivalent of "being left-handed" but that's not right. Left-handedness comes from spinor indexes, which are completely unrelated to the $SU(2)$ rotation taking place.

Well, "explanation" is in the eyes of beholder. For example, Pati-Salam model is actually claimed to be left-right symmetric, with $SU_L(2) \times SU_R(2)$. The $SU_R(2)$ portion is claimed to be broken at some higher energy level by some ad hoc Higgs-like mechanism, thus hardly a true explanation of  chirality.

What is the origin of your singular statement that "all GUTs ... are said to contain $(2)_$ and to explain it by embedding it in some larger group"? Who talks about "explanation"?

I immediately regretted using the word "explanation" after posting my question. What I meant was this: imagine we start from the GUT perspective and break it into the SM. Without knowing what the L subscript referred to a priori, it would never be possible to conclude it referred to left-handedness. It would simply be doublet under SU(2), not necessarily related to left-handed components of spinors.
Or do GUTs contain this information as well?

L and R are abstract separate species of spinors which couple in very special/exceptional ways (mass terms) with each other. You have learned from the SM that they march to their own drummer and have very different quantum numbers. GUTs include and integrate this just-so arbitrary information, otherwise they would be useless and irrelevant. To the extent that this inclusion is tricky and tight, the overarching GUT is "explanatory", and we marvel at it's working...
